# Facebook fql like table removed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api

Anyone knows if facebook is removing the like table completely from fql?

I can no longer see like table in fql list of tables. the [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) shows not found, but i can still access the like table [Graph Explorer Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20user_id%20from%20like%20where%20object_id%20=%20%22584042898287637%22)

```
SELECT user_id from like where object_id = "584042898287637"
```

**Bug or Not!?**

maybe its a bug or maybe they are removing the like table, trying to find out, so we can save time on development if they are removing.

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hIlrnjRciYcJ:developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in load it from google cache. i think page has been removed.

Comment: i like your idea, but real question depends on weather they will remove the functionality from it too or not. whats the point of implementing and then they remove it!

Comment: for real answer you may post your question in developer group https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: facebook company developers are also on stackoverflow to help solve problems. https://developers.facebook.com/support/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Bug. so its not removed.

got answer from facebook at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/120899048109637